# Definition Query with Current_Date?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, definition-query

I have a date field called ExprDate and I want to set a definition query to select all records from today's date plus the next 7 days.

This is what I have:

ExprDate >= CURRENT_DATE +7

The expression is returning values, but not for the current date and next 7 days only. Any thoughts?

I am working on a file geodatabase on 10.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current expression is looking for dates that are 7 days or more than the current date.

Try:

```
ExprDate <= (CURRENT_DATE + 7) AND ExprDate >= CURRENT_DATE
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned, the above only works in some database environments.  I ran into an issue implementing the above solution for data that was stored in a SQL database.  Below is the Definition Query I used to get the last 30 days of data:

```
DATEDIFF(d, FIXED_DATE , GETDATE()) <= 30 AND NOT FIXED_DATE > GETDATE()
```

Comment: Note that this will not work on all data sources.  In a database you'd need to use a date function supported by that database (and these are *very* different).

Answer (score 0):

As Vince mentioned in his comment, the actual query varies on the database.

For **Oracle**, it would look something like this:

```
ExprDate <= trunc(SYSDATE + 7) AND ExprDate >= SYSDATE
```

Note: this is untested.